# How to get Advanced BrowseForFolder window in InnoSetup?

Tags: inno-setup, inno-setup-v6

As you can see on the image,

[image: Image 1]

browsing folder in InnoSetup's installer looks old-style.

How can i achieve this kind of browse for folder window?

[image: Image 2]

Comment: I would not call it old style. That is the browse folder control. The other is just the file dialog with a flag set to only show folders.

Comment: Inno Setup uses the legacy `SHBrowseForFolder` API https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/BrowseFunc.pas#L96 and that's why the old folder browse dialog is displayed. For Windows Vista and above, the new (more than 10 years) `IFileDialog` API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog However, this is something the developers of Inno Setup should do, not you.

Comment: Looks like there is no solution. Thank you

Comment: It is possible, but it would be a lot of work to do.