Is it possible to use the IFileDialog folder picker instead of BrowseForFolder dialog for the Inno Setup?
Currently I succeed to make it open GetOpenFileName-based file picker instead of BrowseForFolder dialog:
function SelectFileDialog(var ResultPath: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := GetOpenFileName('', ResultPath, '', 'All Files|*.*', 'txt');
end;

procedure BrowseButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  FilePath: string;
begin
  if SelectFileDialog(FilePath) then
  begin
    // Extract the folder path from the selected file path
    WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := ExtractFilePath(FilePath);
  end;
end;

WizardForm.DirBrowseButton.OnClick := @BrowseButtonClick;

Since we all know that BrowseForFolder is really big no for user side. How to use IFileDialog with FOS_PICKFOLDERS to do this?


https://stackoverflow.com/q/57061535/850848
